# php error warnings , its going well on localhost but error while get online

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, header, web

There are some errors that i found on my site while i try to do some database function like edit-delete-insert
it used to be fine when im tried it on localhost , 
but now since the web online , these errors show up ,

the warnings are like this

```
DELETE FROM `admin` WHERE `adminID` = 'AD002'
```

> Warning: header(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   /home/gemila14/public_html/cms/scripts/delete_admin.php on line 7
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/gemila14/public_html/cms/index.php:2) in
>   /home/gemila14/public_html/cms/scripts/delete_admin.php on line 7

so actually the `delete/insert/edit` function still work well , but these errors always showed up and i have no any date function on my php file. 
the things that make me confuse is , its work well on localhost , only error on my online website.
im kinda new in this php things and i really dont know how to fix it , hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: add error_reporting(E_STRICT) either in php.ini or your configuration file

Comment: after i search it , we can edit php.ini file on webhost through .htaccess sir ? 
its wrote 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^cms\/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/cms\/login\.php" [R=301,L] ----- so how and where to put that error_reporting(E_STRICT) , thanks

Comment: you can put it on configuration file of your website which is included in all other files

Comment: like this error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT ^ E_NOTICE);

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the default timezone in your php configuration. Look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php for further information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your webhost's PHP settings doesn't have any timezone set.

From the PHP online manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Put something like this into your script:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); ?>
```

And for a list of supported timezones, see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php